# boolean return help to find fix

Tags: ios, swift, return, boolean, new-operator

i have simple problem I want to return this one:

```
let results = prices.filter{
            if($0.MultipleSearchString != nil){
                predicate.evaluate(with: ($0.MultipleSearchString?.lowercased())!)
            }else {
                self.loadPricesFromDb()
            }
        }
```

but I have problem with it, because it giving problem like:
Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Bool' and I dunno why
Can someone explain me this?

Comment: filter expects you to return a boolean for each comparison. for example `prices.filter { $0 > 50.0 }` (based on prices being `[Double]`. its hard to give you an exact answer without more information/context as to what you are doing and what prices actually contains

Comment: Wrong usage. You should check it : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893557-filter

Answer (score 1):

You're using the filter function wrong.

Filter with an inline closure will evaluate each member of the array with the logic in the provided closure, and return an array of elements that satisfy that logic, e.g.:

```
let results = prices.filter {
    $0.MultipleSearchString != nil
}
```

The above will have results with all elements that have `MultipleSearchString` different from nil.

It's also bad to call a function that presumably loads the data from database since it will trigger on (almost) every iteration.

You need to refactor your code to better work with your intended solution.